# How to Know which UUID Perform Read And Which one Perform Read When scanned

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was able to describe the UUIDS in android app using  discover services in android studio  it is showing list of UUIDS

How can I know which one is for Write and Read, can anyone please explain

I can see the list of UUIDS  but how can we find what UUID is for write operation

Answer (score 0):

Once you have discovered the available services and characteristics you can call [getProperties()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic#getProperties()) on each BluetoothGattCharacteristic you discovered. This will return a bit mask containing flags showing which property this characteristic supports. You can then compare the flags to e.g. [PERMISSION_READ](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic#PERMISSION_READ) to check if it is readable:

```
if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ)) {
    // Characteristic is readable
}
```